# Installing Cuckoo on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, anaconda, cuckoo

I decided to try to install Cuckoo on Ubuntu 22.04,recently installed Anaconda, to run Python2's scripts, because are fundamental to make it run.

And I'm stuck on this error:

```
`error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      Cuckoo is Python2-only at the moment! Please use Python 2 to install it, i.e., `pip2 install -U cuckoo`.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.`
```

This is the output error to: `sudo pip install -U cuckoo`

I also created a virtual environment and activated Python2's environment.

I just don't understand why this isn't working.

Tried to search online but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks